# gluon android applyRetrolambda fail

Tags: android, javafx, gluon

I am trying to run the android task for a gluon project but it's failing with an `IllegalArgumentException` and giving the following error:

```
> Task :Android-messengerApp:applyRetrolambda FAILED
Retrolambda 2.5.3
00:00  INFO: Bytecode version: 50 (Java 6)
00:00  INFO: Default methods:  true
00:00  INFO: Input directory:  C:\Users\zinou\java workspace\Android-messenger\Android-messengerApp\build\javafxports\tmp\android\retrolambda\input
00:00  INFO: Output directory: C:\Users\zinou\java workspace\Android-messenger\Android-messengerApp\build\javafxports\tmp\android\retrolambda\output
00:00  INFO: Classpath:        [C:\Users\zinou\java workspace\Android-messenger\Android-messengerApp\build\javafxports\tmp\android\retrolambda\input, C:\Users\zinou\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar]
00:00  INFO: Included files:   all
00:00  INFO: JVM version:      10.0.2
00:00  INFO: Agent enabled:    false
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.LambdaClassDumper (file:/C:/Users/zinou/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.orfjackal.retrolambda/retrolambda/2.5.3/8cd446aba8756a3548c936765172912662a25765/retrolambda-2.5.3.jar) to field java.lang.reflect.Field.modifiers
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.LambdaClassDumper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
00:00 ERROR: Failed to run Retrolambda
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:185)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:168)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.ClassAnalyzer.analyze(ClassAnalyzer.java:25)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Retrolambda$1.visitClass(Retrolambda.java:71)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.files.ClasspathVisitor.visitFile(ClasspathVisitor.java:29)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.files.ClasspathVisitor.visitFile(ClasspathVisitor.java:11)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Unknown Source)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Retrolambda.visitFiles(Retrolambda.java:107)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Retrolambda.run(Retrolambda.java:68)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Main.main(Main.java:28)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Android-messengerApp:applyRetrolambda'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.2\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 47s
6 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

I am using Gradle 4.10.1, compileSdkVersion 28, jdk 10.0.2, jfxmobile plugin 1.3.11.

Comment: What is your jfxmobile plugin version?

Comment: @José jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.11

Comment: You can use 1.3.13 now, but you need to run Java 8

Comment: i did but i'm still getting the same error

Comment: Can you update the error log when you run with Java 8? Also post your build.gradle file.

Comment: You have to use Java 8 for this. Please update your question if you still have any issue.

Comment: i tried everything i found on the internet but correctly setting up a gluon project was very annoying, i will stick to desktop javafx for now

Comment: Have you tried the [starting guide](http://docs.gluonhq.com/getting-started/) or any of these [samples](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples)?

Comment: i checked the starting guide but not the samples, will check now thank you sir